# Set volume in NAudio

Tags: c#-4.0, naudio

I'm using `NAudio.dll` in a C# application. I found that `IWavePlayer` has the property  `Volume` but it's obsolete.

```
 public interface IWavePlayer : IDisposable
    {
        [Obsolete("Not intending to keep supporting this going forward: set the volume on your input WaveProvider instead")]
        float Volume { get; set; }

       //..........................
    }
```

So what should I do to set the volume? Does anyone have an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the implementors of `IWavePlayer` still have a `Volume` property (for example, `WaveOut` and `DirectSound` out do), so just keep a reference to the concrete class rather than the interface. The property on the interface was made obsolete as not all implementors of `IWavePlayer` are able to support this.

In any case, it is often best to control the volume of the samples you are passing to the `IWavePlayer` yourself. There are many classes in NAudio that allow the modification of stream volume, particularly those inheriting from `ISampleProvider`. Look at the NAudioDemo source code and see how volume modification is implemented for an example.

Comment: I didn't find the NAudioDemo source code. Where is  it available?